# I am trying to use infinite scroll with my wordpress theme but it does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Thanks for your time to help me out.

I have a wordpress website: http://techchef.org/bridco/ , in this website i am using wordpress 3.8.1; in the theme i want to use infinite scrolling; i try to use different plugin, like wp_infinitescroll , scrolling plugin; none of that work so i try to use a custom way to make it done.

So i use the steps mentioned in the tutorial here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination--wp-24873 ;

however i am not sure but it looks there is small change which required in wordpress 3.8.1, mentioned below,

in old wordpress version for query post we used 
`query_posts(array('paged' => $paged, 'post_status' => 'publish'));`

in new wordpress version for query post we used 
`query_posts(array('page' => $paged, 'post_status' => 'publish'));`

*instead of "paged" we use "page"*

i tried that but it does not work too, so i turned back that  to the original one "paged"

**For Infinite Scroll I use**

for infinite i use the below mentioned code

**In function.php**

```
function wp_infinitepaginate(){ 
    $loopFile        = $_POST['loop_file'];
    $paged           = $_POST['page_no'];
    $posts_per_page  = get_option('posts_per_page');

    # Load the posts

    query_posts(array('paged' => $paged, 'post_status' => 'publish'));
    get_template_part( $loopFile );

    exit;
}


add_action('wp_ajax_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');    // if user not logged in
```

**In header.php i used**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadArticle(pageNumber) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop', 
        success: function(html){
            jQuery("#main .container").append(html);    // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                    if  (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()){
                          // run our call for pagination
                    }
            }); 
</script>
```

But it does not work, please help, guide me what i am doing wrong in it, or what is missing, even it is not showing any js error, but i found here it gives 0 value 
http://techchef.org/bridco/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved that by changing a function of loop in function.php as per my theme i have mentioned below: more over i have changed get_query_var('paged') with get_query_var('page')

## Load the posts

```
     $loop_paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : $paged;
     query_posts('orderby=date&order=ASC&paged=' . $loop_paged);

                            if ( have_posts() ) :
                                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                                endwhile; 
                                echo '</ul></div>
                                <div style="clear: both"></div>';
                                                       endif;
```

Comment: Sir, This code was not even listed in your question.

Comment: @Ovidio lacomi respected ovidio, thank you for your concern, however actually because of that it was not loading sending the correct data to the ajax file; so i have checked call my theme content loop here instead of the defaut one.

Answer (score 0):

You have miss part of js to call loadArticle and which pageNumber to load

```
   var count = 2;//for first load
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                   loadArticle(count);
                   count++;
                }
        });
```

Comment: it looks it not even getting the navigation or it does not geting the correct value from ajax data file

Comment: now you have doubled part with window scroll (check page source in browser) just one under another

Comment: ahh my bad let me remove that

Comment: did that but it does not put effects on it

Comment: try to put with alert instead ajax call to see is it firing    {alert('bottom reached'); count++; }

Comment: but again its not getting the posts:( if you enter this url your will find is it giving us the value "0" http://techchef.org/bridco/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: in ajax there is a call data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop', 

so when i call the url like this it gives me null
http://techchef.org/bridco/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=infinite_scroll&page_no=2&loop_file=loop

Comment: when you put url in browser you miss a POST part, which include page info, that is reason for "0". Remove alert, this part is working ok, for testing purposes, replace js in http://techchef.org/bridco/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php with some page with static code like <h1>works OK<h2>, and if it will appended right we will focus on wp ajax page. let me know.

Comment: thanks budy its started working now i have replaced query_post code with the same code i used in the theme however its not appending yet, i will update here once i done or if i have any query during append. Again many thanks